# Import 3 XYs to draw a line

Tags: qgis, line, xy

I have decimal XYs for 3 data point to create a line.

Do I need to convert the table to a WKT format such as?

```
LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30, 40 40)
```

I have multiple locations to import to create several shapes from a csv that are lat/long datapoints.

Comment: Perhaps you could show us a few lines from your CSV and we might be able to give you a complete solution?

Comment: Here are the 3 data points that I am trying to draw a line with. I have multiple lines to draw at once.   These are all XY data points that I need to connect with a line.  (39.86877269 -80.92013232) (39.86985366 -80.92115984) (39.87312988 -80.92582732)

Comment: Here is more data:   SURF_LAT SURF_LONG LAND_LAT LAND_LONG END_LAT END_LONG
39.86877269 -80.92013232 39.86985366 -80.92115984 39.87312988 -80.92582732
40.14961477 -81.01741939 40.15060381 -81.01856846 40.15513965 -81.02537973
40.14549531 -81.01317548 40.14688564 -81.01348206 40.15822715 -81.01786838
39.86792978 -80.93322071 39.86885521 -80.93310877 39.87459716 -80.94110598
40.08862615 -80.93322119 40.09089321 -80.93160372 40.10243538 -80.93896177

Comment: Is that in a text file or a spreadsheet or what? Also, the formatting is destroyed in comments, so edit your question. This can be done in QGIS by formatting WKT strings.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is visualize this line in QGIS for 3 XYs data points, you can directly use **QuickWKT** QGIS plugin for this job. I **copy/paste** your WKT line format in window's plugin and result, after click in OK, is at following image:

[image]